# "VerifyError: Expecting to find object/array on stack" when using ASM to monitor object creation in Java?

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

What I want to do is to monitor the object creation and record a unique ID for that object. So I use ASM to monitor the "NEW" instruction. In my method vistor adapter:

```java
public void visitTypeInsn(int opcode, String desc){
    mv.visitTypeInsn(opcode, desc);
    if (opcode == NEW){
        mv.visitInsn(DUP);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "org/.../.../MyRecorder", "object_new",
                "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false);
    }
}
```

In `MyRecorder.java`:

```java
public static void object_new(Object ref){
    log("object_new !");
    log("MyRecorder: " + ref);
    log("ref.getClass().getName(): " + ref.getClass().getName());
}
```

However, these code result in `java.lang.VerifyError: (...) Expecting to find object/array on stack`. I have no idea why this can not work. If this way is not right, how can I monitor the object creation?

---

Actually, I also tried to monitor `object.<init>` instead of monitor the `NEW` instruction. However, with the following code, it throws `java.lang.VerifyError: (...) Unable to pop operand off an empty stack`:

```java
public void visitMethodInsn(int opc, String owner, String name, String desc, boolean isInterface) {
    ...
    mv.visitMethodInsn(opc, owner, name, desc, isInterface);
    if (opc == INVOKESPECIAL && name.equals("<init>")) {
        mv.visitInsn(DUP);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "org/myekstazi/agent/PurityRecorder", "object_new",
                "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the resulting bytecode look like? You can use `javap` on the compiled class to figure that out.
I guess that you are probably intervening too early after the `NEW` opcode and would need to wait until `INVOKESPECIAL` was invoked.

Comment: @nrainer I don't know what the resulting bytecode looks like because I use java agent to transform the classes when they are loaded so I did not dump them to the disk. I think you mean insert those instructions after the object is initialized? I also tried that but sadly it also can not work smoothly.

Comment: The problem is that you can't do much with an uninitialized object. Resulting bytecode will look like `new C, dup, invokestatic ...PurityRecorder.object_new, dup, invokespecial C.<init>`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thanks for your comment! Could you explain more about "can't do much with an uninitialized object"? I think the bytecode is exactly like what you described. But I do not understand why it throws VerifyError, since it looks valid.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.2 Search for uninitialized.

Comment: You cannot pass uninitalized values to other methods but the initialization method. However, I don't see a problem with you second approach using `<init>`. Maybe there is some other issue somewhere in your code?

Comment: @JojOatXGME Thanks for your comment! In the second method, it seems that when it executes `DUP`, the operand stack is actually empty. I guess after the execution of `<init>`, no initialized object will be pushed on the operand stack. Is that possible?

Comment: In short, consider the default constructor: `aload 0; invokespecial j/l/Object.<init>(); return`.

Answer (score 2):

The object instantiation is separated into two instructions. This can make it difficult to work with object instantiation. It was actually the biggest problem in multiple of my projects with ASM. The simple expression `new Integer(0)` might compile to the following code.

```
new java/lang/Integer                       ═╤═
dup                                         ═╪═══╤═
iconst_0                                     │   │  ═╤═
invokespecial java/lang/Integer.<init>(I)V   │  ═╧═══╧═
                                             ↓
```

*(The ASCII art on the right shall represent the lifetime of values on the stack. The first column represents the first item on the stack, the second column the second item on the stack, and so on.)*

The reference created with `new` cannot be used until it is initialized by `invokespecial`. Therefore, you cannot put you instrumentation directly after `new`. In the example above, you could put the instrumentation behind `invokespecial`. However, you need to distinguish it from calls to the super constructor. A statement like `super(0)` might compile to the following code.

```
aload_0                                     ═╤═
iconst_0                                     │  ═╤═
invokespecial {super class}.<init>(I)V      ═╧═══╧═
```

This two examples might cover the two most common cases where `<init>` is called. If you don't do anything with the value created by `new Integer(0)`, a compiler could also decide to skip the `dup` instruction. I'm not sure if they actually do it. Anyway, the first example wourld become the following code.

```
new java/lang/Integer                       ═╤═
iconst_0                                     │  ═╤═
invokespecial java/lang/Integer.<init>(I)V  ═╧═══╧═
```

This can still be handled by injecting `dup` behind `new`, and `invokestatic` behind `invokespecial`.

Anyway, if you want to handle even more exotic cases, the bytecode could also contain instructions like [`dup_x1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup_x1) or [`dup_x2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup_x2). [`GeneratorAdapter.box(Type)`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.html#box-org.objectweb.asm.Type-) actually generates such code. Some "lazy" bytecode manipulators could also cause `new` instructions where the instance is never initialized before it is removed with `pop`. As you can see, working with object instantiations in bytecode can take a lot of work. However, depending on your situation, you might not need to suport all this cases. Unfortunately, I don't have the experiance to estimate which cases you need to support.

---

Here is an example that doesn't handle `dup_x1` and similar instructions. Therefore, it would not work with code generated by [`GeneratorAdapter.box(Type)`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.html#box-org.objectweb.asm.Type-). Beside that, it seems to work reasonable well in my tests. It uses `AnalyzerAdapter` to get some information about the operand stack.

```java
public final class InstrumentationMethodVisitor extends AnalyzerAdapter {
  public InstrumentationMethodVisitor(
      String owner, int access, String name, String descriptor,
      MethodVisitor methodVisitor) {
    super(ASM8, owner, access, name, descriptor, methodVisitor);
  }

  @Override
  public void visitTypeInsn(int opcode, String type) {
    super.visitTypeInsn(opcode, type);
    if (opcode == NEW && stack != null) {
      mv.visitInsn(DUP);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
    if (opcode == POP && stack != null && stack.get(stack.size() - 1) instanceof Label) {
      mv.visitInsn(POP);
    }
    super.visitInsn(opcode);
  }

  @Override
  public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String descriptor, boolean isInterface) {
    if (opcode == INVOKESPECIAL && name.equals("<init>")) {
      boolean hasRelatedNew = stack != null && stack.get(stack.size() - getAmountOfArgumentSlots(descriptor) - 1) instanceof Label;

      super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);

      if (hasRelatedNew) {
        mv.visitMethodInsn(
            INVOKESTATIC,
            "org/myekstazi/agent/PurityRecorder",
            "object_new",
            "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V",
            false);
      }
    }
    else {
      super.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, descriptor, isInterface);
    }
  }

  private static int getAmountOfArgumentSlots(String descriptor) {
    int slots = 0;
    for (Type type : Type.getArgumentTypes(descriptor)) {
      slots += type.getSize();
    }
    return slots;
  }
}
```